Add custom refactoring pattern using Resharper
I have hundreds occurences of this kind of lines in my app :
public ICommand MyCommandName => ReactiveCommand.Create(TriggerCommand);

I tried without luck to add a Custom Pattern in resharper to change it to :
private ICommand _MyCommandName;
public ICommand MyCommandName => _MyCommandName ??= ReactiveCommand.Create(TriggerCommand);

Here is my pattern :

the pattern is ambiguous and can't be saved.
Here are the placeholders :





Not an answer, just pointing out that your ??= is not thread-safe. You may want to consider making _MyCommandName lazily initialized.

I'm not using R# in Visual Studio anymore, therefore I don't have access to the Structural Search and Replace feature in VS. However, using JetBrains Rider I was able to solve your task with the following RegEx which should also work in Visual Studio 
Search:
public (\w*) (\w*) \=\> (\w*)\.(\w*)\((\w*)\)\;

Replace:
public $1 _$2;
public $1 $2 => _$2 ??= $3.$4($5);


I could do it with Visual studio with the Search & Replace (with regex) :
Search :
public ICommand (\w*) => Reactive
Replace :
private ICommand _$1;\n\t\tpublic ICommand $1 => _$1 ??= Reactive

I accept this solution, even if it isn't done using Resharper
